# While loop keeps repeating

Tags: c++, while-loop, switch-statement

I setup a while loop where i want to choose r or h, i dont want to use forloops but i want to use a switch why is it when i enter r or h it keeps repeating a million times the cout for that case? I cant get it to just say it once..

```
while (chooseMove == 'r' or 'h')
{
    switch (chooseMove) 
    {
    case 'r':
            cout << "you chose r";

        break;
    case 'h':
        cout << "you chose h";
        break;
    }




}
```

I also tried it with forloops and had the same problem i cant figure it out

Comment: you may want to add a `<< endl` in there!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you mean is `while (chooseMove == 'r' or chooseMove == 'h')`. What you've currently written is equivalent to `((chooseMove == 'r') or ('h'))`, and `'h'` evaluates as `true`.

---

Maybe you were also asking for help with the input logic:

```
char c;
bool success = false;

while (std::in >> c)
{
  switch(c) {
    case 'r': /* ... */ success = true; break;
    case 'h': /* ... */ success = true; break;
  }

  if (success) break;
}
```

This will also terminate if the input stream is closed, and you can use `success` to inspect the success of the operation.

Comment: Is 'or' really a C++ operator?

Comment: @BlackBear: yes, it's an alternative to `||`. E.g. [see here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ciso646/) (the header file itself isn't needed). Another popular alternative is `??!??!`.

Comment: Just tested it. Wow! "or" compiles with g++ and vim syntax highlighting recognizes it as a keyword.

Comment: you and mooing duck both have half the answer.

Comment: Does the OP need help designing the ambient input logic, too?

Comment: Really, you got the important part.

Answer (score 2):

Because that's what you programmed it to do.

If you want the loop to stop or pause (and say, wait for input), you should add that code into the loop.

```
while (chooseMove == 'r' or chooseMove == 'h')
{
    switch (chooseMove) 
    {
    case 'r':
            cout << "you chose r";

        break;
    case 'h':
        cout << "you chose h";
        break;
    }
    std::cin >> chooseMove;  //stop and wait for more input
}
```

Comment: Holy crpa i didnt even realize that. I see because it now asks for the value again it needs to know where to go...

Comment: you and kerrek s.b. both have half the answer.

Comment: oh, I focused on the "doesn't stop" problem, and he on the "always" part. :D  I fixed mine.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem:

```
while (chooseMove == 'r' or 'h')
```

Try this instead:

```
while ((chooseMove == 'r') || (chooseMove == 'h'))
```

When you write (how did this even compile? `or` isn't C++):

```
chooseMove == 'r' or 'h'
```

It is interpreted as:

```
(chooseMove == 'r') or ('h')
```

The statement `'h'` is always true, so the `while` loop runs forever.

Comment: `or` actually _is_ C++.   § 2.13

Comment: IMO: I use `||` since every coder knows about it and is familiar with it, whereas most people thing `or` is an error :(

Answer (score 0):

What does `chooseMove == 'r' or 'h'` mean?  According to the C++
standard, this is grouped as `(chooseMove == 'r') or ('h')`; the
implicit conversion of `'h'` to `bool` then results in `(chooseMove ==
'r') or ('h' != 0)`.  The second condition will always be true.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (chooseMove == 'r' or 'h')
```

which is equivalent to this:

```
while ( (chooseMove == 'r')  or true)
//same as while ( (chooseMove == 'r')  || true)
```

So this is infinite loop. Note that `or` and `||` are same thing.

What you want is this:

```
while ( (chooseMove == 'r')  or (chooseMove == 'h'))
//same as while ( (chooseMove == 'r')  || (chooseMove == 'h'))
```